# 502 after long running asp.net controller actionresult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller ActionResult in which I call prodManager.ProcessFile(). This takes 2 or 3 minutes during which I will get a 502 error in the browser because IIS times out. It's probably not a good idea to increase the time it takes IIS to timeout. How can I modify this to perhaps call it from AJAX on the previous view and then display a status when the entire actionresult is done running or even have some javascript call a different function which will give a status update ever 5 seconds or so?

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessProducts(UploadViewModel model)
        {
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime endTime;
            TimeSpan totalTime;            
            PulProcessor prodManager = new PulProcessor();
            string inputFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files/incoming"), model.ProductsFileName);
            string outputPath = Server.MapPath("~/files/pul");

            prodManager.ProcessFile(inputFile, outputPath);

            endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            totalTime = endTime - startTime;

            ViewBag.StartTime = startTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.EndTime = endTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.TotalTime = totalTime.ToString();
            ViewBag.TotalOutput = prodManager.Products.Count.ToString();
            ViewBag.ProductCounter = prodManager.RecordsProcessed;
            ViewBag.FileName = prodManager.ProductsFileName;
            ViewBag.ExFileName = prodManager.ExceptionsFileName;
            ViewBag.Exceptions = prodManager.BelowCost.Count.ToString();

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My controller method was taking too long and timing out. I solved this buy writing a SignalR hub to process and output my files while reporting the status of the operation to a status bar on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could try encapsulating the processing logic into an [async task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx). Start and store the `Task` in a static "running tasks" collection, probably with a key. Return an ActionResult to indicate that the "request has been submitted". Next you can "poll" via AJAX, and get the status of the `Task` via it's key.